# Image not Showing in my site

Tags: html, image, razor

This IS NOT SHOWING THE PIC IN MY SITE

```
<img src="C:\\Users\\dave\\Desktop\\myProject\\UsersPics\\4\\1.png" />
```

IF I HOVER WITH THE MOUSE ON THE img IT GIVE ME AN OPTION TO DO ENCODE IN BASE 64 RESULT SOMETHIN LONG AND UGLY THAT WORKING

http://jsfiddle.net/0knayyjL/1/

My question is how i do the Conversion in razor syntax on the img path

Comment: HOW I MAKE RAZOR DO IT FOR ME????? I NOT GOING TO PRESS ENCODE BILLION TIMES MANUALY WHEN SOMEONE UPLOAD A PIC

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It helps a lot if you can **describe your problem concisely** without abusing the use of blockquotes and the caps lock key.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a local machine path like that. Think about who's receiving the HTML. The client receives the HTML. `C:\\Users\\dave\\Desktop\\myProject\\UsersPics\\4\\1.png` Probably isn't on their machine. You have to host the image as part of your site (usually the Content folder) and use a relative path to that (such as `/Content/1.png`).

Comment: i want to save the pic one folder back from the ui folder

Comment: @ronit As long as that pic is in a directory served by the web server and you provide a valid relative path to it, it'll work.

Comment: @ronit Well if you want to pay the airfare and my consulting fee, I'll come over and take a look. Otherwise you should update your question with a better description of how you've set things up.